# Storing an Array of React.js Elements in Javascript to some File or any Storage so it Could be Used Later

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

**Note:** I can't use Node FS module because I don't know much about npm and fs.

I'm creating a small dummy game where a user can click a button to get a 'duck' on screen which is just a `<img>` but all this is being done in React.js. I have an array `duckMem` which stores the Elements created by React via `createElement` call. The code looks like this:

```js
var duckMem = [];
var e = React.createElement('img',{src:'src'},null};
duckMem.push(e);
ReactDom.render(...);
```

I now want to save the state of the game, i.e. the ducks currently on screen. When the user closes and opens the **Local HTML** file, all the ducks should be there.

**What have I tried:**

```js
saveByteArray(duckMem, "duck.txt");
```

```js
var saveByteArray = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, name) {
        var blob = new Blob(data, {type:"application/octet-stream" /*"octet/stream"*/}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = name;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

And

An example [here](https://stacktips.com/tutorials/html5/reading-and-creating-text-files-using-jquery-and-html5-file-api) which I modified a bit to download the txt file on window close event.

**What have I achieved so far:**

I was able to get a file with this content:

`[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]`

which is an array of objects corresponding to `duckMem`.

```js
typeof React.createElement
```

also evaluated to `Object`.

**What am I trying to do:**

I have used a text file so I could easily see the data in the file (if it is random or non ASCII characters then the data has been successfully written, as I think) otherwise any file extension can be used.

I would create a file with binary data in it and when user opens the HTML file, read that binary data and render all the ducks to restore the saved state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you are going about this the right way.
Whether the output of `React.createElement()` is actually serializable (aka can be represented as a string) is unclear to me at this point.

But one thing is certain:
If it is the state that you want to save, write the actual `src` attributes in the file. `duck.txt` will just list URLs for the ducks.
This has some advantages: for starters, it makes that file more maintainable.
And, this list of URLs can become a state entry that forces your components to rerender whenever it (the list) changes.

When you need to restore the state

```
// Read the URLs from the file.
// We expect ducks to be an array of strings.
// We will pass this array to the React Component that renders the ducks.
const ducks = readFromFile("duck.txt");


// Function that renders the ducks.
// It receives a list of ducks URLs as props
function DucksRenderer(ducksURLArray) {

  return (
    <div className="ducks-container">
      {
         ducks.map(duckURL => <img src={duckURL}/>)
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: It seems you are doing this in the browser, a better approach to save this data would be to use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

```
// To write the list of ducks urls
localStorage.setItem('ducksURLs', JSON.stringify(ducks));

// To read the list
const ducksURLs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ducksURLs'));
```

Comment: I appreciate it @KibongeMurphy. All my search was centered on creating a file and never stumbled on localStorage. I wrote some 80 lines to write a file and reading it but now I have a 3 liner. Thanks.